# How can I do a for loop in R to do multiple plot, with multple data frames?

Tags: r

Sorry I'm a newbie in R.
I have multiple data frames, `product.43`, `product.98`, `product.103`, that contain the sales of each product over the time and have another variable, `index`, that contains the codes for each product:

```
 products
    43
    98
    103
```

If I do one by one it should be something like this:

```
plot(product.43[,3],product.43[,2],type="o")
plot(product.98[,3],product.98[,2],type="o")
plot(product.103[,3],product.103[,2],type="o")
```

what I'm trying to do is this:

```
plot(product.i[,3],artigo_agreg.i[,2],type="o")
```

So I want to substitute the `i` for the product code that is in `index` with a `for` loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referring to objects using variable strings in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588008/referring-to-objects-using-variable-strings-in-r)

Comment: You're best off having the data.frames in a list rather than as separate objects. Then looping through them is trivial, and you can also do nicer things with `lapply`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `get()`. Here is an example:

```
abc.1 <- 123
abc.2 <- 456

for(i in 1:2){
  var <- paste('abc', i, sep='.')
  x <- get(var)
  print(x)
}
## [1] 123
## [1] 456
```

As you can see, you can create a variable (`var`) that holds the name of the variable you want to use. Then , you can `get()` the value of the variable using its name.

In your specific case, this would be something like this:

```
for(i in index) {
  var <- paste('product', i, sep='.')
  product.i <- get(var)
  # Do whatever you need to do with product.i
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want.
Thanks!